# Help with Predicate calculus

Tags: logic

I need to prove this theorm ∃y(Fy → ∀xFx). meaning i need to arrive at this result based on no assumptions. help?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py) as well as [Proof of Drinker paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807092/proof-of-drinker-paradox)

Comment: As per linked posts, the proof strategy will be based on LEM: **∀xFx ∨ ¬∀xFx**, applying Disjunction Elimination to it.